# .rvmrc trust hangs/freezes

Tags: rvmrc

I'm having problems trusting an rvmrc as a non-root user.  If I cd to the project directory I get the rvm trust prompt

*Do you wish to trust this .rvmrc file? (appdir/.rvmrc)
y[es], n[o], v[iew], c[ancel]>*

but when I pick y[es] it hangs indefinitely. rvm rvmrc trust has similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

I used set -x to figure out where rvm trust was freezing.

> set -x
> cd appdir
Do you wish to trust this .rvmrc file? (appdir/.rvmrc) y[es], n[o], v[iew], c[ancel]>
>y
..
..
..
/usr/local/rvm/scripts/db /usr/local/rvm/user/rvmrcs _usr_share_batsd_current__rvmrc delete


I then ran */usr/local/rvm/scripts/db /usr/local/rvm/user/rvmrcs _usr_share_batsd_current__rvmrc delete* with sudo.  This removed the entry in /usr/local/rvm/user/rvmrcs.  After that entry was delete I was able to trust the rvmrc.

Comment: Using `set -x` helped me find a similar, but different problem with a incorrectly configured .rvmrc file.